# Split Button Formatting Off Depending on Browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I have a jQuery splitbutton on my page that I am having a formatting issue with.  Per my company's design standards, I am basically transforming a link into a button.  Everything works fine, functionality is perfect, but depending on which browser you are using (I'm testing with IE and Chrome), the right side of the split button is just a little bit longer than the main button.

I think my issue is in this CSS class:

```
.default_button.medium_toggle {padding: 14px 5px 10px;}
```

If I change the 10px to 9px, it works in IE.  The way it is, it works in Chrome.  (Side note, in Chrome, if you zoom in on the page, it's off, but I'm not too concerned with that)

Any suggestions?  All of my code is at [jsfiddle.net/lwisdom43/6ErCs/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/lwisdom43/6ErCs/3/).  I placed it here because I didn't want to copy all of my CSS for these two buttons in this post.  Again, this is all based on company design standards.  Thank you for any help you may be able to provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put some text inside the second a-tag, you will notice that the source of your problem actually is another problem.

You set `height` and `width` in `.default_button.dropdown_toggle` and padding in `.default_button.medium_toggle` but not in `.default_button` or `.medium_button`.

Remove `height` and `width` from `.default_button.dropdown_toggle` and padding from `.default_button.medium_toggle` and it will have the same height (it will probably work if you set the height in `.default_button`)